# How to use routing with Branch.io fallback utl

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I'm trying to setup Branch.io that when the user clicks on the myapp.app.link/abcd, if the app is not installed and not available for the device, it will fall back to www.mywebsite.com/abcd and show the web version that corresponds to that link.
I cannot find anywhere in the docs how to configure this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *may* have to make sure that a default redirect url is not setup on the dashboard.

Use a link such as `https://example.app.link/kJNbhZ1PrF?$fallback_url=https://www.website.com/kJNbhZ1PrF`